# Batch create text files, each new file with different text pulled from excel

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create multiple text files from template text file; however, in each newly generated file there should be added a new line of text pulled from excel row.

for example:

template text file content

```
Line1
Line2
```

And Excel file has several rows, each with different text, e.g.

```
Row1text
Row2text
Row3text
```

So what I need to do is pull from Excel rows the text and add it to the newly generated text file, based on text template file,

so the result would be like this

GeneratedText1.txt

```
Line1
Line2
Row1text
```

GeneratedText2.txt

```
Line1
Line2
Row2text
```

GeneratedText3.txt

```
Line1
Line2
Row3text
```

As many as there are rows in excel, so many the text files should be generated. The names of the new files should be also predefined somewhere.
What's the best way to do it? Some command line would help?

Comment: Are these excel rows actually in an excel sheet, or have they already been exported to txt?

Comment: Is your "excel" file really a CSV file? If so, then this is very doable with batch. Or is it a binary Excel file? in which case a batch solution is a bad idea. If you truly have an Excel file, then you are going to want to use vba.

Comment: I can use just a csv file I can accomplish this goal with csv. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=1
for /f %%l in (input.csv) do (
  >GeneratedText!i!.txt type template.txt
  >>GeneratedText!i!.txt echo %%l
  set /a i+=1
)

endlocal
```

**Edit:** Modify the batch file like this to have it read the output filenames from the 1<sup>st</sup> field of `input.csv`:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=, tokens=1*" %%f in (input.csv) do (
  >"%%~f" type template.txt
  >>"%%~f" echo %%g
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost working well, but the line from csv just adds itself to the last line of the new text file, and not on the new line, e.g Line2Row1text. How can this be resolved? Thank you

Comment: Either add a trailing newline to the file `template.txt` or insert a line `>>GeneratedText!i!.txt echo.` after the `type template.txt` instruction.

Comment: Yes, this is working well. Last thing, is it possible to define the unique file names by myself without the autogenerated numerical ending, e.g. Randy.txt John.txt. Sandy.txt etc rather than GeneratedText1.txt, GeneratedText2.txt, GeneratedText3.txt. I tried to modify such filenames in the script, but messed up the function. Thank you

Comment: I don't think that's possible in batch (unless you provide the file names as a separate field in `input.csv`). You'd need to switch to VBScript or some other scripting language for that.

Comment: If I provide the file name fields in the csv, e.g. in 1st column, and the content in 2nd column, how would the batch script look then? Thank you